# Persistent Debian Live HDD

Tags: debian, mount, livecd, persistence

I want to make a persistent live boot in which I can store my data on a debian iso booted from a hard drive. So I downloaded debian-live [(here)](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/), modified the grub entry to be able to boot into the live-system:`

```
menuentry "Debian modified" {
  set iso_path="/live-boot/debian-live.iso"
  export iso_path
  loopback loop $iso_path
  set root=(loop)
  set loopback="findiso=${iso_path}"
  export loopback
  linux /live/vmlinuz-5.10.0-13-amd64 boot=live persistence components keyboard-layouts=de splash verbose "$loopback"
  initrd /live/initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64
}
```

I can boot into my live system but when I want to store data in it, after a reboot the data is lost. Am I doing something wrong in the grub entry here?

Here could be also useful information for you, `df -ha` on the live boot gives me the following output (shortened to relevant parts):

```
FS        Size  Used   Avail  Use    Mounted on
/dev/sda1 ...   ...    ...    ...    /run/live/persistence/sda1  <= my main partition (also from where the boot is happening)
/dev/loop0 ..   ...    ...    ...    /run/live/medium
/dev/loop1 ..   ...    ...    ...    /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs     ...   ...    ...    ...    /run/live/overlay
overlay   ...   ...    ...    ...    /
tmpfs     ...   ...    ...    ...    /usr/lib/live/mount
/dev/loop0 ..   ...    ...    ...    /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
/dev/loop1 ..   ...    ...    ...    /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
/dev/sda1  ..   ...    ...    ...    /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda1
tmpfs     ...   ...    ...    ...    /usr/lib/live/mount/overlay
```

and the fstab on the live boot gives me the following output:

```
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

The `mount | grep overlay` returns:

```
tmpfs on run/live/overlay type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
overlay on / type overlay (rw,noatime,lowerdir=/run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs/,upperdir=/run/live/overlay/rw,workdir=/run/live/overlay/work)
tmpfs on /usr/lib/live/mount/overlay type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
```

I also manually tried to mount the overlay directly to the persistent partition (sda1) with the persistent storage as upperdir / workdir which results in

```
overlay on / type overlay (rw,noatime,lowerdir=/run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs/,upperdir=/run/live/persitence/sda1/rw,workdir=/run/live/persistence/sda1/work
```

of course, I created those directories there on the persistent partition ;-) ... but it is still not working to store data persistently and I don't know what to do.

So how can I modify this all to be able to store data on the live-iso and when rebooting without losing the data stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original advice

You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a persistent live drive from the current Debian live iso files.

- **mkusb-dus and select 'dus-persistent'**

  This 'classic mkusb' method creates partition table and several partitions. See details at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) and [that link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent).
- **mkusb-plug and select 'persistent' (or in mkusb-sedd '--pder')**

  This method 'semi-clones' the iso file using sed to get the boot option `persistent` into the otherwise cloned content from the iso file to the target device. In addition to that the remaining part of the drive 'behind' the copy of the iso file will be formatted into a file system that will provide persistence.

It should be straight-forward. `mkusb-dus` works both in graphical mode and text mode. `mkusb-plug` works only in graphical mode, but you can use `mkusb-sedd` 'manually' in text mode and get the same result, because `mkusb-plug` is a graphical front end of `mkusb-sedd`. See details at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug).

### Advice modified after discussion with the OP

After a discussion (in comments) I suggest the following method to create a persistent live Lubuntu system in a drive with Ubuntu Server. (You may prefer another Ubuntu flavour, all current official Ubuntu desktop systems and community flavours should work here.)

- I created an Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS by extracting [jammy-preinstalled-server-amd64.img.xz](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/jammy-preinstalled-server-amd64.img.xz) and cloning it to an SSD. It is convenient with mkusb.
- I booted into Ubuntu Server and checked that it works correctly. The user name is 'ubuntu'. In this process I also changed password from 'ubuntu' to something else. The server expanded its root partition automatically to use the whole drive.
- I see no good way to use a file for persistence, instead I suggest to boot from another drive and use `gparted` to shrink the root partition of Ubuntu Server (by moving its tail end), and in the unallocated space created, create a new partition with the ext4 file system and label it `writable`.

  [image]

  You can see a padlock symbol for `/dev/sdc1`. It indicates that the partition is mounted, and you must unmount it before you can shrink it.
- Then boot into the Ubuntu Server and create a directory `Live` in the home directory: `/home/ubuntu/Live`
- Get `lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso` for example via `sftp` into this directory.
- create a menuentry for the persistent live system

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
  ```

  and make it look something like the following

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec tail -n +3 $0
  # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
  # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
  # the 'exec tail' line above.
  #
  menuentry "Lubuntu 22.04 ISO" {
     set isofile="/home/ubuntu/Live/lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
     # or set isofile="/<username>/Live/lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
     # if you use a single partition for your $HOME
     rmmod tpm
     search --set=root --fs-uuid cc633893-7fde-4185-b852-7b886f51ff7f
     loopback loop ($root)/$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject persistent
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
   }
   set timeout_style=menu
   set timeout=10
  ```

  Please notice that

  - I use the UUID of the root partition of Ubuntu Server `cc633...` in order to identify the target device in a reliable way. You can find this UUID via

    ```
     lsblk -o name,size,uuid
    ```

    you should modify this UUID to match your particular system.
  - `persistent` is added to the 'standard' live linux command line.
  - The two last lines provide a 'hard' way to make the grub menu be displayed.
- These edits of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` will be activated by running

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

  and you should notice it the next time you boot (or reboot).

Comment: I suggest that you start by using a tool (and my tool is mkusb) to make it easy to create the first persistent live system. When it works, if you wish, you can either look at the working system and/or some relevant part of the tool and/or ask additional questions in order to learn how to make a persistent live system 'from scratch' by yourself. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know if this will work out as planned because I only have one hdd inside my pc and I want to have the live-iso saving the changes to that one hdd. A USB or another drive is not available. Is this possible at all with this tool, or in general?

Comment: **Yes, it is possible** with mkusb-dus to select an internal drive, and it is possbile with mkusb-sedd too (but not with mkusb-plug, because of its unplug and plug procedure to identify the drive). And it is possible, to do it manually or with some other method too, unless the tool prevents it (for example in order to protect internal drives from overwriting by mistake). But bear in mind the mkusb grabs the whole drive. If you want some kind of dual boot, you have to do it manually, or which I have done, install the other system **after** the persistent live system was installed.

Comment: Okay, well then I am afraid I have to do it manually... I think the main problem is with the overlayfs which does not point to my persistent hdd (`sda1`). I tested with RUFUS and there the overlayfs pointed to the persistent partition of my USB but as pointed out, I don't want to have a Live-USB/CD, I want to do a kind of dual boot where I can switch between those systems on the persistent hard drive without any extra partitions. Do you know where I can modify the overlayfs to write on the hdd permanently - even from the live boot?

Comment: Is there an installed system in the internal drive, and you want to keep that installed system, only 'borrow' part of the drive space for the persistent live system? Do you want persistence via a partition or via a file? Must it be Debian, or could you consider another Linux distro? And do you want to boot the live system from the HDD itself, or do you want to boot it from USB but have the file or partition for persistence on the internal drive?

Comment: There is already an installed system on the internal drive (Ubuntu Server 22.04). With partitions on it (sda1: /, sda2 /var/log, sda3: /srv/nfs). On sda1 I have the most space since it is the root and where I want to store data. The live system I downloaded was Debian but could also be f.e. Ubuntu. I want to boot live from the hdd itself to the live system. And the live system *must* be persistent and I cannot create any new partition. The persistence itself should be pretty scalable, so I think a file wouldn't be the best idea, unless it only works with a file :-)

Comment: Well, if you don't want to create a new partition, there is not much choice, you must use a file for persistence. Unless you run the persistent live system in a virtual machine. Then (inside the virtual machine) you can let the persistent live system 'do whatever it wants to do', it will not disturb the host system.

Comment: An Ubuntu live 'grub-n-iso' system according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Separate_boot_drive_using_ISO_boot_alias_grub-n-iso_from_template) can be easily modified with the boot option `persistent` and a file named `casper-rw` with an ext2, ext3 or ext4 file system inside would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already have the `persitence` (for debian, equal to `persistent` on ubuntu) in the grub entry as mentioned in my post. But as said the live boot debian is not persistent at all. Do I have to put an ext2/3/4 file inside the debian live iso to be able to store data persistently? Or what are the next steps to accomplish persistency of the live boot?

Comment: I think it will be easier with Ubuntu Desktop or Lubuntu or some other Ubuntu community flavour. When there is a boot option `persistent`, it will look for a partition with the label `writable` or `casper-rw` or a file with the name `casper-rw`. This file should be 'treated like a partition', you should create an ext2, ext3 or ext4 file system in it, and the live Ubuntu will use it for persistence. You need not point to it explicitly, it is enough that the storage for persistence is seen with its label or name.

Comment: This should be possible also with Debian, but I am not as familiar with it (compared to Ubuntu), so I am not sure what works and what details are necessary in a 'grub-n-iso' configuration with Debian.

Comment: But is there a limitation for that file especially in size? I've read that there is a limit of 4GB?

Comment: 4GiB is a limit only in the FAT32 file system. In the ext4 file system of your Ubuntu Server, there is no such file size limit.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain where to create the `casper-rw`-file? In Ubuntu 20.04+ it must be named `writable`, am I right?

Comment: Both `writable` and `casper-rw` work for a partition. I know that `casper-rw` works for a file. Maybe also `writable` works for a file to make it recognized for persistance. The file should be created in the root file system of the installed Ubuntu Server system. You can use `dd` to create it. There might be faster ways, but these might create a file with 'holes', which is not good for a file with a file system (and would be bad for a swap area too).

Comment: I tested and had problems with a file named `casper-rw` or `writable` in an ext4 file system. It seems you are right, that Ubuntu expects a FAT32 file system (and hence a 4 GiB size limit). So your specifications are impossible. You must accept some modification, and I think the best one is to shrink the root partition of the Ubuntu Server (by moving its tail end), and in the unallocated space created, create a new partition with the ext4 file system and label it `writable` or `casper-rw`. I will modify my 'answer' by describing such a system and how to create it.